# How to serialize a DateTimeOffset into a binary stream

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

I'm wondering what would be the best way to serialize a `DateTimeOffset` into a binary stream (using a `BinaryWriter`) and deserialize it again (using a `BinaryReader`).

To serialize a `DateTime`, I have:

```
    public void WriteValue(DateTime value)
    {
        _writer.Write(value.ToBinary());
    }
```

and

```
    public DateTime ReadDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.FromBinary(_reader.ReadInt64());
    }
```

What is the best approach to serialize/deserialize a `DateTimeOffset` in terms of performance and storage size?

Comment: A DateTime is a double with the whole number the number of days from 1/1/1900 (day 1) and the fraction the fraction of a day.  A double is stored as a 32 bit floating point number.  So using a Int64 will give rounding errors.

Comment: BinaryFormatter does this very easily.  It sort of looks like you are rolling your own serializer?

Comment: @Plutonix: yes, I do.

Comment: You could serialize its UtcTicks and Offset.Ticks properties, deserialize with the DateTimeOffset(long, Timespan) constructor.  If space is crucial then you could serialize the Offset property in units of minutes, a short is enough.

Comment: @jdweng: `ToBinary()` is returning a Int64.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've implemented your suggested approach. I still wonder if calling `TotalMinutes` and `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` is the fastest way. But I guess it's the trade-off to save the 6 bytes compare to just serializing the `Ticks`.

Comment: If you can't figure this out by using Stopwatch then you are doing it wrong.  Micro-optimizing this is in general pointless, file I/O is a lot more expensive than code like this.

Comment: @Plutonix In my experiment BinaryFormatter uses 86 bytes per DateTimeOffset. When limited file/message size is required of the binary format, using BinaryFormatter for DateTimeOffsets might not be the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a comment by Hans Passant, I've came up with the following solution. To serialize:

```
    public void WriteValue(DateTimeOffset value)
    {
        WriteValue(value.DateTime);
        WriteValue((short)value.Offset.TotalMinutes);
    }
```

And deserialize:

```
    public DateTimeOffset ReadDateTimeOffset()
    {
        var dateTime = ReadDateTime();
        var minutes = ReadInt16();
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
    }
```

So these method call to the existing serialization methods for `DateTime` as outlined in the question.

I still wonder if this is the most efficient way to do this. How fast is it to call `TotalMinutes` and `TimeSpan.FromMinutes`?

Answer (score 2):

Not that my answer adds much but I have written this little utility for packing and unpacking DateTimeOffset:

```
public static class DateTimeOffsetExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Packs DateTimeOffset to bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTimeOffset"></param>
    /// <returns>10 byte packed bytearray</returns>
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(dateTimeOffset.Ticks).
           Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)dateTimeOffset.Offset.TotalMinutes)).ToArray();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads 10 bytes from a buffer and turns back to DateTimeOffset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">Buffer</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Offset to read from</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTimeOffset FromBytes(byte[] bytes, int offset)
    {
        var ticks = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, offset);
        var offsetMinutes = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, offset + 8);
        return new DateTimeOffset(ticks, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(offsetMinutes));
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I don't really understand the offset parameter of FromBytes though. Wouldn't that always be 0? Or do you need to store something after converting to the byte array (other than the byte array itself) to enable you to get the DateTimeOffset back i.e. some kind of offset.

Answer (score -2):

The correct approach to serialize and deserialize Date-Time objects (any language) is the use of a timezone and daylight savings independent value, for example, UTC time. On deserialization, either stay in UTC (if used by code only) or pick the current local timezone offset (if read by humans). This way you avoid issues with different timezones and, even if the values stays in one country, you avoid issues when daylight savings change between serialization/deserialization.

The `DateTimeOffset.UtcTicks` property (64bit integer) is a good candidate for binary serializers. Be careful not to use `DateTimeOffset.Ticks` as this property includes any offsets.

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;
using (var w = new BinaryWriter(...))
{
    w.Write(dto.UtcTicks); // do not use dto.Ticks!
}
```

Deserialization looks clumsy, since there is no simple way to create a `DateTimeOffset` from UTC ticks. If the object is never shown to a human, you can skip the conversion to local time.

```
using (var r = new BinaryReader(...))
{
    long utcTicks = r.ReadInt64();
    dto = new DateTimeOffset(utcTicks, TimeSpan.Zero).ToLocalTime();
}
```

In terms of storage, you require 8 bytes = 64 bit. I'm not sure about deserialization performance (not tested), but I think it should be as fast as it can get.

EDIT: To preserve timezone (offset) information,

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;
using (var w = new BinaryWriter(...))
{
    w.Write(dto.Ticks);
    w.Write(dto.Offset.Ticks);
}

using (var r = new BinaryReader(...))
{
    long ticks = r.ReadInt64();
    long offsetTicks = r.ReadInt64();
    dto = new DateTimeOffset(ticks, new TimeSpan(offsetTicks);
}
```

Comment: Reducing DateTimeOffset to a timezone and daylight savings independent value as @Patrick Stalph suggests, causes LOSS OF INFORMATION; I would argue that it is NOT (always) the CORRECT approach to serialize Date-Time objects.  DateTimeOffset stores both a timezone offset and a time (whether this is in UTC or in the specified timezone is an implementation detail), this provides three kinds of time: the wall time of the event, the UTC timestamp, and the time in the viewing user's local timezone.  Storing only UtcTicks looses the original wall time of the event.

Comment: You are right, but I guess it is quite rare that one country is interested in the actual wall clock of another :-)

Comment: We write software to monitor events across the world.  You can imagine that someone entering a building at 03:00 during the night (in their timezone, not mine) should trigger a different response then someone entering at 08:00 in the morning.  At other times the operator wants to know the event's time in his own timezone, since an event that occurred recently might require a different response than an event that occurred a couple of hours ago.